# Creating tables with the SQLite-net library

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm

I'm researching SQLite - .net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) in order to add a local storage to my project.
I've come up with a few questions:

1. The tables are created per ***model***, and then in order to create the tables this code should be used:

   ```
   var db = new SQLiteConnection("foofoo");  
   db.CreateTable<Stock>();  
   db.CreateTable<Valuation>();
   ```

   The problem is, in a MVVM approach, where would this be written?
   I thought about the bootstrapper.cs but I'm not quite sure how effective it is.
2. In one of the examples, this is the example code of a certain model:

   ```
   public class Valuation  
   {  
       [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]  
       public int Id { get; set; }  
       [Indexed]  
       public int StockId { get; set; }  
       public DateTime Time { get; set; }  
       public decimal Price { get; set; }  
   }
   ```

   Does the `[Indexed]` statement apply **ONLY** to `StockId`, or to all three `StockId`, `Time` and `Price`?

Comment: Attributes (which is what `[Indexed]` is) only apply to one property.

Answer (score 0):

Data Service! Just create a DataService class. Pass it the path to the database or look it up config. Have the constructor create the SQLiteConnection, create tables, add any default data.

If you are using an IOC container you can register DataService for use in your ViewModels. Consider registering with the create immediate flag set to True so the database gets initialized right away.

Sorry I don't have a working example at the moment.